# How do I join two tables with on multiple values

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How Do join the same tables on multiple values like

```
select * from table tt1 join table tt2 on tt1.value1=tt2.value2 and on tt1.value5=tt2.value6
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It's unfortunate `JOIN`s are not covered in any documentation anywhere, and the only way you can learn about them is through question and answer sites!

Comment: Do you want both conditions to be true for a single row, or for either condition to apply? (I frequently find people use "and" in this form of pseudo-code when they really mean "or")

Comment: ANd BTW research why you should not use select * while you are researching how to correctly use joins. @JNK, I'd upvote your comment a million times if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the second "on", specify the type of join

```
select * from table tt1 inner join table tt2 on tt1.value1=tt2.value2 and tt1.value5=tt2.value6
```

Answer (score 0):

You're awfully close:

```
SELECT *
FROM table tt1
INNER JOIN table tt2
    ON tt1.value1 = tt2.value2
    AND tt1.value5 = tt2.value6
```

Just drop the additional "ON" ...